# Solving the differential equation $y’-\frac{2x-1}{x^2}y=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m having problems solving this equation and I was hoping to find someone here who can help me.

$$y’-\frac{2x-1}{x^2}y=1$$

Here is my attempt:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your attempt? That would make this question more well-received.

Comment: Your attempt was close but I'm not sure why you dropped off the "1" and made it a zero?  If you leave the "1" intact you should be correct.

Comment: I did these types of equations at school, and for every exercise of this kind, my teacher equated the equation to 0. I didn't understand the reason either, I tried to follow the steps shown by him.

Comment: @NataliaHăngănuț, you solved the homogeneous equation $$y’-\frac{2x-1}{x^2}y=0\;\;,$$now you need to get a particular solution of $$y’-\frac{2x-1}{x^2}y=1\;\;.$$

Comment: @NataliaHăngănuț, please, could you write your attempt directly without using pictures?

Comment: @NataliaHăngănuț , the reason why your teacher equate the equation to zero is because to find the complementary solution for the differential equation then add it to the particular solution to find the general solution for the equation

Answer (score 3):

You tried to solve the homogeneous equation, which is fine as a first step.
$$
\frac{y'}{y} = \frac 2x -\frac{1}{x^2} \Rightarrow \log|y| = \log x^2+\frac 1x \Rightarrow y = c x^2 e^{1/x}
$$

You can now try $y(x) = c(x) x^2 e^{1/x}$ in the original equation and compute $c(x)$.

You'll conclude that $y(x) = c x^2 e^{1/x} + x^2$.

Comment: The differential equation is linear in $y$ you don't need variation of parameters step to solve it

Comment: @amin You are correct, but this way you don't need to remember the formula for the linear case... This is equivalent to determine the integrating factor.

Comment: @PierreCarre, you should correct your solution. Actually, $y(x)=cx^2e^{1/x}+x^2$

Comment: @Angelo corrected!

Answer (score 2):

the equation is linear in $y$ it's solution is as follows

first you find the integrating factor which is $\mu(x)$

\begin{gather} \mu(x) =e^{\int_{}^{}\frac{-2x+1}{x^2}dx}=\frac{1}{x^2}.e^{\frac{-1}{x}} \end{gather}

then use it into the next equation

\begin{gather} \mu(x).y(x)=\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x^2}.e^\frac{-1}{x}dx=e^\frac{-1}{x}+c \end{gather}

substitute by $\mu(x)$ in the last equation you get that

\begin{gather} y(x)=x^2+cx^2 \sqrt[x]{e} \end{gather}